# I am trying to write a search query on MYSQL to find the users

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL for a given data model where I have and entity 'concerts' connected to the entity 'Attended' which is connected by the entity 'People'.

Here I am given a one to many and many to one relation respective to the entities I mentioned. I am asked to find the People.Firstname who haven't attended a single concert. I tried implementing this using the INNER JOIN of Concerts and Attended to People. 
My Search Query is as follows :

```
Select People.FirstName from People 
    INNER JOIN Attended 
        on People.Id = Attended.Customer
    INNER JOIN Concert
        Where Attended.Concert != Concert.Id
            GROUP BY People.FirstName
```

I get bunch of First names out but Idk for sure if the query I made gives the right output.

Comment: What is `Watch.Concert`? I don't see any table named *Watch*.. 
Could you not do something like this: `SELECT People.Firstname FROM People WHERE People.Id NOT IN (SELECT Attented.Customer FROM Attented)` ?

Comment: @LeviJohansen Hi sorry mis-typed it, i meant Attended.Concert != Concert.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your attempt:**

```
Select People.FirstName from People       -- get names from people
    INNER JOIN Attended 
        on People.Id = Attended.Customer  -- limit results to those who
                                          -- can be matched with an attendance
    INNER JOIN Concert
        Where Attended.Concert != Concert.Id  -- repeat Attended, and thereby People, 
                                              -- for every concert that doesn't match 
                                              -- with Attended
            GROUP BY People.FirstName     -- group by name 
                                          -- (makes it only show each name once)
```

Your list would consist of a names for people who did attend concerts, but each name would be repeated for every concert that is not the one they attended - *but since it is grouped, each name only appears once.*

*People who has never attended any concert would not be in the list.*

**This is what I would have done:**

```
SELECT People.Firstname 
FROM People 
WHERE People.Id NOT IN (
     SELECT Attented.Customer FROM Attented
)
```

This may not be the most resource-efficient solution, and your hunch to use *`JOIN`* is well based, I think. **Etienne Obriot** has a good solution that uses *`JOIN`*.

Comment: GOLD ANSWER!!!!!

Comment: Sorry there you go :))

Answer (score 1):

People who didn't attend any concert should not be reference in your Attended table by definition.

So you could maybe try to do your requests with a left or right join and put a criteria on records with null id, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT People.FirstName from People 
LEFT JOIN Attended on Attended.Customer = People.ID
WHERE Attended.Customer is null;
```

This is how I thought my query :

By using a left join, I'll get all records from left table (here People), with matching record from right table (here Attended).

The missing records (i.e. records on which there is no match with given on clause) are replaced by null value - thus, if I can't find an Attended record for my people ID, I'll get Null for Attended Customer column.

My WHERE clause filter all Attended record which are not null, leaving me with only people who don't have matching Attended record - these are people who don't go to concert.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. It might be even more helpful if you could describe a bit more how this works and how it would help - you'll probably attract more up votes that way as well :)

Comment: Hi Tom, you're right. I'll edit this right away.

Comment: Excellen @EtienneObriot, i got a very different output. Could you explain to me what is wrong with mine.

Comment: You basically asked for a list of *People.FirstName* if attendance could be found on that person, and if it could find a concert that was different than the one attended.. and since there is more than one concert it found the latter.. but the names belong to people who really have attended concerts